# delete last inserts on rollback with trigger

Tags: sql, sql-server, triggers

When I insert three rows in a table I have this trigger that checks if the sum of the three rows is equal to 10, else a rollback is done. The problem is that this trigger only fires when the third row is trying to be inserted, which means that the first two rows are inserted. But now I want to alter this trigger so that if the sum isn't 10 of the three rows, I want the two first rows that was inserted to be deleted. Does anyone know how to alter the trigger so that the two last inserted rows will be deleted?

Current trigger code:

```
ALTER TRIGGER [dbo].[trg_Sum] ON [dbo].[Table]
AFTER UPDATE, INSERT
AS

IF EXISTS (
SELECT TOP 1 NULL FROM (
SELECT SUM(Procentandel) AS Sum
FROM Table
WHERE    
      ID = (SELECT ID FROM inserted) 
AND 
      ID2 = (SELECT ID2 FROM inserted)
GROUP BY ID, ID2
HAVING COUNT(*) = 3) t
WHERE t.Sum <> 10
)

BEGIN
RAISERROR ('The sum must be 10!',16, 1)
ROLLBACK TRANSACTION
END
```

Comment: Your trigger has **MAJOR** flaw in that you seem to assume it'll be called **once per row** - that is **not** the case. The trigger will fire **once per statement**, so if your statement affects 3 rows, you'll get the trigger fired **once**, but then `Inserted` and `Deleted` will each contain 3 rows. Which of those 3 rows will your code select here?? `(SELECT ID FROM inserted)` - it's non-deterministic and you're ignoring the other 2 rows. You need to rewrite your trigger to take this into account!

Comment: No, the trigger fired and showed the error msg on the third insert statement, since every statement inserted a new row in the table and the trigger only checked the sum once the last insert was made, so you misunderstood my post. But anyway, I solved it by simply replacing the code line "rollback transaction" with the code line "DELETE Table WHERE ID = (SELECT ID FROM inserted) and ID2 = (SELECT ID2 FROM inserted)", and now it works as desired!

Comment: Your trigger is **still going to fail** if you ever have an `INSERT` or `UPDATE` which affects *more than one row* at once .....

Answer (score 0):

The following trigger would maintain the invariant "No combination of id1 and id2 having exactly three rows that don't sum to 10".

```
create trigger dbo.trg_sum on dbo.trigger_test after update, insert as
delete
    t
from
    dbo.trigger_test t
where exists (
    select
        'x'
    from
        dbo.trigger_test t2
    where
        t.id1 = t2.id1 and 
        t.id2 = t2.id2 and
        exists (
            select
                'x'
            from
                inserted i
            where
                i.id1 = t2.id1 and
                i.id2 = t2.id2
        )
    group by
        t2.id1,
        t2.id2
    having
        count(*) = 3 and
        sum(t2.Procentandel) != 10
);
```

To see why it is done in a set based way, consider the following statements:

```
insert into dbo.trigger_test (
    Id1, Id2, Procentandel
) values 
    (1, 1, 1),
    (1, 1, 1),
    (1, 1, 1);

insert into dbo.trigger_test (
    Id1, Id2, Procentandel
) values 
    (1, 1, 1);

insert into dbo.trigger_test (
    Id1, Id2, Procentandel
) values 
    (1, 1, 1),
    (1, 1, 1);
```

That said, triggers feel like the wrong design for this. It seems more like a table with three columns, one for each value slot would be easier.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming all 3 rows you're referring to are being modified in the same transaction, you can do this:

```
ALTER TRIGGER [dbo].[trg_Sum] ON [dbo].[Table]
AFTER UPDATE, INSERT
AS

IF (SELECT SUM(Procentandel) FROM inserted) <> 10)
BEGIN
RAISERROR ('The sum must be 10!',16, 1)
ROLLBACK TRANSACTION
END
```